¿Cómo importar en mongo con mongoimport excepto la columna _id?
He hecho una exportación de algunos artículos (mongoexport) para contar con un backup de los artículos, ya que, tenía que aplicarle unos cambios a dichos artículos, ahora quiero importar los originales (y dejar los modificados), pero me da error:
index: _id_ dup key:

Entiendo que la mejor opción hubiese sido exportados sin el _id, imagino que será algo así:
mongoexport --db mydb --collection articles --query '{"conditionName": 1}' --type=json --out test_articles.json | jq 'del(.[]._id)'

Sin embargo, dado que ya están exportados con el _id, ¿cómo puedo indicarle a mongoimport que no tenga en cuenta ese valor? ¿o qué solución puedo aplicar aquí?
Si la solución que me sugieren involucra perder los modificados, no pasa nada, porque la próxima vez haré bien la exportación (sin el _id), volveré a aplicar los cambios e intentar importar nuevamente.

El campo _id es un campo "obligatorio" en MongopDB. Por lo cual, si bien puedes exportar una colección de documentos, no habrá forma que mongoexport omita este campo. Las soluciones que encuentres pasan por eliminar manualmente en cada documento el campo _id, bien usando herramientas como sed (en un terminal de Linux) u otras herramientas similares. Mi preguntas es ¿Qué escenario tienes para que estés importando documentos sobre una colección que ya contiene datos? mongoexport y mongoimport son herramientas para respaldo de colecciones y bases de datos.

En tu pregunta dices: "ahora quiero importar los originales (y dejar los modificados)", eso no tiene ningún sentido. No puedes tener 2 elementos con el mismo _id en una colección. Por lo cual tu plantemaiento tiene un problema. Es como querer modificar un documento de texto y tener tanto el original como el modificado con el mismo nombre en la misma carpeta. No se puede. Un respaldo de los datos no sirve para esto. Lo suyo es usar el concepto de versiones de MongoDB.

Por último: _"la próxima vez haré bien la exportación (sin el id), volveré a aplicar los cambios e intentar importar nuevamente" no te funcionará. Tendrás todos los documentos originales en un respaldo, todos los modificados y no modificados en la colección y con la importación del respaldo sin _id, MongoDB creará un nuevo campo _id por cada documento del respaldo, dando como resultado que tengas tanto originales que no se han modificado con una copia extra (proveniente del respaldo), los modificados (sin copia extra) más sus contrapartes no modificadas provenientes del resplado.

Agrega "_id:0" a la projeccion o consulta y esto la quita

¿A la consulta de mongoimport? te paso la que uso: mongoimport --db myDb --collection articles --file backup_articles.json

¿Puedes detallar más?

Acabo de encontrar la forma de exportar (mongoexport) sin el "_id" pero de poco me sirve para darle solución a este problema, como que ya es un poco tarde.

Buenas Guest (cuenta de invitado?) por favor, edita tu respuesta para que sea mejor recibida y expliques mejor la solución propuesta. Mira [answer] para ayudarte mas.

Excorpion, la respuesta nunca fue modificada.

Esto no responde la pregunta, por ello te he votado negativo. Lo que sugieres sólo aplica a procesos de consulta de datos. Lo que el OP plantea no es nada relacionado con una consulta de datos, es tener o mantener una versión de documentos en la colección.
